# CSS Grid bringing up unnecessary horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, css-grid

I was working with this basic css grid layout, where essentially I wanted to create a grid which is 3row (538px 200px 90px) and 4column(repeat(4,1fr)) wide.
But the moment I define the container (.main) as display: grid, an unnecessary horizontal scroll appears. **I want to allocate 100% width not more than that**, hence I even tried width: 100vw, but that seems to not work either. The horizontal scrollbar seems legit, considering my row heights add up to more than 100vh, but why is there an excess in vertical area? 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr should divide the available space between 4 children.

**Question 1: Then where is this little excess horizontal area coming from (which is making it necessary for me to scroll)? And how do I limit my max-width of grid to 100vw, hence not having this horizontal scrollbar?**

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
    </div>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 538px 200px 90px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

I put that border to visualize what is going on.

**Question 2: If I could actually see the grid lines dividing the container into 12 pieces, that would be dope. Any way of doing that? Where I could actually visualize what's going on with dotted lines separating each grid item maybe?**

Comment: `width:100vw`  + `border` without `box-sizing` reset to `border-box` makes your box be  100w + 2px +2px  of width ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yes, I do understand border-box. But my problem persists even without the presence of the border. I have tried removing the border, but the horizontal scroll remains, stilll.

Comment: width:100vw doesn't care about the vertical scrollbar. width:100% would, but in fine, a block always span the whole avalaible width . remove width unless you need it less than the space avalaible. to show twelve columns in a backgound, you may use on `.main`:  `background:linear-gradient(to left, red 2px, transparent 2px);
  background-size:8.33% auto;`

Comment: example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwrRgPW

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I tried width: 100%, it still poses the same problem. As for the visualisation aspect, I can see how your proposed solution would be helpful. But the scrollbar problem is just annoying. ._.

Comment: remove width , there is no need for a block if it's to span the wole width. ;) as i wrote earlier, ... or reset box-sizing .... demo  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ExPyXgM

Comment: Yes, I was being stooopid again. I did do width: 100%. But i forgot to account for the border (+4px) this time around. Like you mentioned in the first case. Thank you so much for the extended help. This was certainly a learning experience for me. By the way, your codepen profile was definitely worth my time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing `width: 100vw` to `width: 100%` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for looking into the matter. I got it fixed already, and yes this was the main fix. Moreover I was new to grid, hence messed up. Now I understand how things work.